# r time series matching

Tags: r

a dataset contains whole year communication break events. The line in the data had a break during the event start and end. The data looks like below

```
comms.break<- data.frame(line = c("line1","line2","line3","line1"),eventstart = c("1/1/2017 7:24","1/2/2017 8:25","1/1/2017 7:24","1/2/2017 9:25"),eventend = c("1/1/2017 7:25","1/2/2017 8:26","1/1/2017 7:29","1/2/2017 10:25"))

> comms.break
   line    eventstart       eventend
1 line1 1/1/2017 7:24  1/1/2017 7:25
2 line2 1/2/2017 8:25  1/2/2017 8:26
3 line3 1/1/2017 7:24  1/1/2017 7:29
4 line1 1/2/2017 9:25 1/2/2017 10:25
```

I would need a new data frame. The first column will be the whole year 1 min time series, other columns will be the line numbers. The value for each line at each timestamp will be 1 if it is not in the above event, otherwise will be 0. The final output will like this

```
    Time               line1  line2  line3 
   1/1/2017 0:00       1       1      1 
   1/1/2017 0:01       1       1      1
    ...............
   1/1/2017  7:24      0       1      0
   1/1/2017  7:25      0       1      0
   1/1/2017  7:26      1       1      0
   ...............
```

Not many ideas how to get above results. Thanks in advance for the help!

**With the help, below code can do the work!**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

comms.break<- data.frame(line = c("line1","line2","line3","line1"),eventstart = c("1/1/2017 7:24","1/2/2017 8:25","1/1/2017 7:24","1/2/2017 9:25"),eventend = c("1/1/2017 7:25","1/2/2017 8:26","1/1/2017 7:29","1/2/2017 10:25"))

# put the data into date objects
events <- comms.break %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(eventstart, eventend), 
            ~ as.POSIXct(strptime(., format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))) %>%
  # now expand it
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Time = seq(eventstart, eventend, by = "min") %>% list) %>% 
  unnest(Time) %>% 
  select(line, Time)

# make a whole year time series
year.start<- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character("1/1/2017 0:00"), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
year.end<- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character("12/31/2017 23:59"), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))


# make the minute vector and join in the events
time_series <- seq(year.start, year.end, by = "min") %>% 
data_frame(Time = .) %>% 
left_join(events, by = "Time") %>%
mutate(counter = 1) %>% 
spread(line, counter, fill = 0) %>% 
select(-`<NA>`)
```

The results are:

```
Time line1 line2 line3
  *              <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1 2017-01-01 00:00:00     0     0     0
  2 2017-01-01 00:01:00     0     0     0
  3 2017-01-01 00:02:00     0     0     0
  4 2017-01-01 00:03:00     0     0     0
.............
445 2017-01-01 07:24:00     1     0     1
446 2017-01-01 07:25:00     1     0     1
447 2017-01-01 07:26:00     0     0     1
448 2017-01-01 07:27:00     0     0     1
449 2017-01-01 07:28:00     0     0     1
450 2017-01-01 07:29:00     0     0     1
451 2017-01-01 07:30:00     0     0     0
```

Comment: Try `spread` from the `tidyr` library.  You might need a dummy variable of all ones, and then fill the missing values with zeroes by setting the parameter `fill = 0`.

Comment: Can you explain some more about why you need to have a row for every single minute? Is the goal just to see when particular lines are not in service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little tricky, but this method works. Note I'm using a few `tidyverse` libraries. `lubridate` standard for dates, and `dplyr` and `tidyr` and great for data manip. If you get a package issue just use `library(tidyverse)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT') # set your timezone

# put the data into date objects
events <- comms.break %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(eventstart, eventend), 
            ~ as.POSIXct(strptime(., format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))) %>%
  # now expand it
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Time = seq(eventstart, eventend, by = "min") %>% list) %>% 
  unnest(Time) %>% 
  select(line, Time)

# get the time range to make the minute table from
time_range <- events %>% 
  pull(Time) %>% 
  range

# make the minute vector and join in the events
time_series <- seq(time_range[1], time_range[2], by = "min") %>% 
data_frame(Time = .) %>% 
left_join(events, by = "Time") %>%
mutate(counter = 1) %>% 
spread(line, counter, fill = 0) %>% 
select(-`<NA>`)
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is very close to what I need. I made small changes and post it again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're looking for. This is a `tidyverse` approach that makes use of the `%within%` operator and the `interval` object type from `lubridate` to check whether each minute lies within an event, and a combination of `gather`, `complete` and `spread` to construct a dataframe with the full range of minutes needed. Note that here we only have mintues from `2017-01-01 07:24:00` to `2017-01-02 10:25:00` since that is the full extent of the example datetimes. The full year of minutes would be much larger and not really justified in using this approach for whatever your goal is unless there are correspondingly many event periods.

This code is also not very extensible to a large number of events right now. I think some clever use of `mutate_at` with an appropriate helper function ought to be able to create the `line` columns properly, and avoid having separate `line_intv` objects, but I was not able to get it to work and resorted to using `bind_cols` and `map_lgl` instead, generating the whole column and then sticking it to the tibble. Improvements appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

comms.break<- tibble(line = c("line1","line2","line3","line1"),eventstart = c("1/1/2017 7:24","1/2/2017 8:25","1/1/2017 7:24","1/2/2017 9:25"),eventend = c("1/1/2017 7:25","1/2/2017 8:26","1/1/2017 7:29","1/2/2017 10:25"))

line1_intv <- comms.break %>%
  filter(line == "line1") %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(dmy_hm(eventstart), dmy_hm(eventend))) %>%
  extract2("interval")

line2_intv <- comms.break %>%
  filter(line == "line2") %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(dmy_hm(eventstart), dmy_hm(eventend))) %>%
  extract2("interval")

line3_intv <- comms.break %>%
  filter(line == "line3") %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(dmy_hm(eventstart), dmy_hm(eventend))) %>%
  extract2("interval")

minutes <- comms.break %>%
  gather(key = "event", value = "datetime", eventstart, eventend) %>%
  mutate(datetime = dmy_hm(datetime)) %>%
  arrange(datetime) %>%
  complete(datetime = full_seq(datetime, 60)) %>%
  spread(key = "line", value = "event") %>%
  select(datetime)

output <- minutes %>%
  bind_cols(line1 = map_lgl(minutes$datetime, ~ any(. %within% line1_intv))) %>%
  bind_cols(line2 = map_lgl(minutes$datetime, ~ any(. %within% line3_intv))) %>%
  bind_cols(line3 = map_lgl(minutes$datetime, ~ any(. %within% line3_intv))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(line1:line3), as.integer)
print(output)

# A tibble: 44,822 x 4
   datetime            line1 line2 line3
   <dttm>              <int> <int> <int>
 1 2017-01-01 07:24:00     1     0     1
 2 2017-01-01 07:25:00     1     0     1
 3 2017-01-01 07:26:00     0     0     1
 4 2017-01-01 07:27:00     0     0     1
 5 2017-01-01 07:28:00     0     0     1
 6 2017-01-01 07:29:00     0     0     1
 7 2017-01-01 07:30:00     0     0     0
 8 2017-01-01 07:31:00     0     0     0
 9 2017-01-01 07:32:00     0     0     0
10 2017-01-01 07:33:00     0     0     0
# ... with 44,812 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I post the whole code after some changes from another user.